# Cannot successfully include external header file through cc_library rule for bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

I have trouble being able to include some header files through a build command in bazel. I followed the [example](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cpp-use-cases.html#adding-include-paths) that they included in the bazel documentation.

This is my BUILD file

```
cc_library(
    name = "hello-greet",
    srcs = ["hello-greet.cc"],
    hdrs = ["hello-greet.h"],
    copts = ["-Imain/include"]
)

cc_binary(
    name = "hello-world",
    srcs = ["hello-world.cc"],
    deps = [
        ":hello-greet",
    ],
)
```

Below is the structure of my directory.

- WORKSPACE
- main

  - include

    - hello-greet.h
  - hello-greet.cc
  - hello-world.cc
  - BUILD

I don't know if this will help, but here is some code for the source and header files.

hello-greet.cc

```
#include "hello-greet.h"
#include <string>

std::string get_greet(const std::string& who) {
  return "Hello " + who;
}
```

hello-world.cc

```
#include "hello-greet.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void print_localtime() {
  std::time_t result = std::time(nullptr);
  std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&result));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  std::string who = "world";
  if (argc > 1) {
    who = argv[1];
  }
  print_localtime();
  return 0;
}
```

When I run the bazel build command, it complains with this error

```
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: missing input file '//main:hello-greet.h'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do what you want by adding [`includes = "."`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.includes) to the `cc_library` (no need to have the `copts`)